# Is there a simple way to test a SAML JIT handler class?

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, identity-provider, jit-handler

I'm in the process of configuring Single Sign-On for my org and this org will require JIT user provisioning. I've written a custom SAML JIT handler class to handle that logic and now I want to test this apex class.

I wonder if there is a quick and easy way to test the SAML JIT handler class without configuring the Identity Provider and initiating the authentication flow from the Identity Provider? The reason for asking this is because my teammate who is responsible for the Identity Provider piece of the project is currently busy. And I wonder if anyone here might know a simple way test a SAML JIT handler class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Really stuck & need some help creating Apex Test class for JIT Class (Auth.SamUtiHandler)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193281/really-stuck-need-some-help-creating-apex-test-class-for-jit-class-auth-samut)

Comment: The link that you provided is related to writing test class for SAML JIT handler class. I don't have problem doing that myself. But thanks anyway @identigral

Comment: Excellent - that's a simple enough way, go for it!